# Create an error in log in Python

Tags: python, error-logging

I'm using Python 2.7 and pyinstaller to create a program. My program uses "print" to display the current progress of my program. What I want is for my program to create an error log in the event of an error, which will show the various statements that have printed to the screen so that I can see it's progress.  Below is a simple program that will cause a zerodivisionerror:

```
import os
os.chdir("C:")
logname="Error 30032014 1832"

def subroutine():
    print "Subroutine started"
    print "Stage1 is complete"
    print "Stage2 is complete"
    a=1
    b=0
    c=a/b
subroutine()
```

This is the result:

```
Subroutine started
Stage1 is complete
Stage2 is complete

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:/Users/Joseph/Desktop/a.py", line 8, in <module>
subroutine()
File "C:/Users/Joseph/Desktop/a.py", line 7, in subroutine
 c=a/b
ZeroDivisionError: integer division or modulo by zero
```

I want a textfile with the name logname (or if the name can be generated automatically with the date and time) to be generated displaying the above displayed information so that I can examine the error.

Comment: Have a look at [the logging package](https://docs.python.org/2/library/logging.html).

Answer (score 1):

Python has built in logging facilities, which you should use for logging.

Here is a link to the docs for logging library: https://docs.python.org/2/library/logging.html

Here is example from documentation on how it is used:

```
import logging
logging.warning('Watch out!') # will print a message to the console
logging.info('I told you so') # will not print anything
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want your `print` statements to print to the log file, you can redirect the output stream to your log file:

```
import sys
stdout = sys.stdout #save the original stdout stream
log_file = open("C:/logfile.log", 'w')
sys.stdout = log_file
print "This happened"  #goes to the log file
print "And that too!"
```

You can do the same with `sys.stderr` to redirect your exceptions to the writable. But of course, [logging](https://docs.python.org/2/howto/logging.html#logging-basic-tutorial) is better suited to that purpose.